# Not enough arguments for format string error when inserting list into database SQL Python

Tags: python, sql, list

I'm trying to insert a list into separate columns of a database

```
print inserter 
params = ['%s' for item in inserter]
sql_query = 'INSERT INTO tablename (coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3, coloumn4, coloumn5, coloumn6, coloumn7) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);' % ','.join(params)
cursor.execute(sql_query)
db.commit
```

But keep getting the error

```
not enough arguments for format string
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

You are using string interpolation in a query.
This is bad, mainly for 2 reasons:

- It is erroneous as you see. The python interpreter is confused between the `%s` for the interpolation and the `%s` for the sql parameters.
- It makes your code vulnerable for sql injection.

You should use a parametrized query:

```
sql_query = '''INSERT INTO tablename (coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3, 
                                      coloumn4, coloumn5, coloumn6, coloumn7)
               VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);'''

cursor.execute(sql_query, inserter) # assuming inserter is a tuple/list of values
```